# How is a go package with a /v<version> URL suffix resolved?

Tags: go

Looking at the library `github.com/redis/go-redis` as an example, it seems to possible to address different versions of the package using an URL suffix stating the major version:

```
go get github.com/redis/go-redis/v9
```

Or in more general terms:

```
go get github.com/foo/bar/v<MAJOR>
```

- How is this achieved as package creator?
- What is the resolution logic here? Does it require GitHub release with a [semver](https://semver.org/) of the same major version to be present in the repository?
- How would a local development setup look like? Can the respective major version be emulated in a depending go application referencing a local version of the package?

Comment: See https://go.dev/blog/v2-go-modules, and https://go.dev/ref/mod

Answer (score 1):

Github repository you mentioned is `github.com/redis/go-redis/`. Open the `go.mod` file and you will see that the module is `module github.com/redis/go-redis/v9`. So for each major version, you will change the module name. For example for version `v10`, module name will be module `github.com/redis/go-redis/v10` and to indicate the version is updated, you have to create a new tag. As in your example the current tag is `v9.0.4`.